# Include specific dependencies with maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using the maven assembly plugin so that I can include specific dependencies(basically I want to
include specific transitive dependencies) class in my jar file. Here is my relevant code snippet from the `pom.xml` -

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  

      </plugins>
  </build>
```

Looks like it is possible from link http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html
 But as soon as mention below code snippet to include two types of dependencies com.companyA.* and com.companyB.* ,**except that
 I do not want to exclude all other dependencies**

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <includes>
        <include>com.companyA.*</include>
        <include>com.companyB.*</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
```

But `pom.xml`  says **invalid content for dependencySets**. I don't know how to achieve objective here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use two `<dependencySet>` entries with mutually exclusive patterns, like so

```
<dependencySet>
  <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>com.mypkg.*:*</exclude>
  </excludes>
</dependencySet>

<dependencySet>
  <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <includes>
    <include>com.mypkg.*:*</include>
  </includes>
</dependencySet>
```

In this case it's copying everything in `com.mypkg` to the `bin` folder, and everything not `com.mypkg` to the `lib` folder

This kind of approach should suffice for what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the same problem with me. Here you can only do part config in pom.xml like this:

```
<plugin>    
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>    
              <configuration>    
                    <descriptors>    
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>    
                   </descriptors>    
              </configuration>    
                <executions>  
                    <execution>  
                        <phase>install</phase>  
                        <goals>  
                            <goal>single</goal>  
                        </goals>  
                        <configuration>  
                            <outputDirectory>d:/temp/stock</outputDirectory>  
                        </configuration>  
                    </execution>  
                </executions>  

         </plugin>
```

but you can config most of assembly config in assembly.xml, like this:

```
<assembly  
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">  
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>  
    <formats>  
        <format>dir</format>  
    </formats>  
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>  
    <dependencySets>  
        <dependencySet>  
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>  
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>  
            <includes>  
                <include>org.tkxing.stock:org.tkxing.stock.test</include>  
            </includes>         
        </dependencySet>  
        <dependencySet>  
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>  
            <outputDirectory>lib/</outputDirectory>  
            <excludes>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-beans</exclude>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-asm</exclude>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-core</exclude>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-aop</exclude>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-context</exclude>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-expression</exclude>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-jms</exclude>  
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-tx</exclude>  
            </excludes>  
        </dependencySet>  
    </dependencySets>  

    <fileSets>  
        <fileSet>  
            <directory>conf</directory>  
            <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>  
        </fileSet>  
        <fileSet>  
            <directory>bundles</directory>  
            <outputDirectory>bundles</outputDirectory>  
        </fileSet>  
    </fileSets>  

    <files>  
        <file>  
            <source>log4j.xml</source>  
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>  
        </file>  
    </files>  

</assembly>
```

hope this could help others